# Magento 1.9: Force Customer to login to access the homepage and other page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

If customer open site then login page show but if the customer enters login details then show the homepage and other product page and catalog page. I have added this code in index.php and 1cloumn.phtml file but its start looping the site

but perfect work on other pages

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code

```
$redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/');
$current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if((!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) && ($current_url != $redirect_url)){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url);
}
```

Comment: perfect working thanks